# Execute statements from Oracle or MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have the code that calls MSSQL stored procedures via java.sql.CallableStatement with row written statemens like:

```
 {? = call ProcedureName(@par = ?)}
```

Now I need to rewrite them to be able to call the Oracle stored procedures.

Is there any converter or something like that which can help me to overcome rewrite them by hand?

I will be glad for an universal way to call stored procedures or functions independently from specific kind of DB.

Comment: Why is this an off-top if I am asking about an unified way to make something   in programming ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you call a stored procedure and override the default value of parameter par? If so the oracle syntax for that would be

`{? = call ProcedureName(par => ?)}`

(assuming your stored procedure is really a stored function, as it returns a value).

I am not aware of any generic method (but that doesn't mean that there isn't one of course) to call stored procedures with the named notation in JDBC. You could of course abstract stored procedure calls yourself with e.g. (simplistic) a method which accepts the name of the stored procedure and a name / value array to pass to it. Depending on the target database type use the oracle or the sql server specific notation in your implementation.

cheers

Comment: Thank's, I already going that way by building  different CallableStatement's from procedureName and parameters.